# What is the Biblical basis for the idea that the 'quality of life' in hell is not the same for everyone?

Tags: biblical-basis, hell, punishment, eternity

What is the Biblical basis for believing that an existence in hell will be appreciably different in quality for each individual - i.e quality or grades of hell? Do proponents of this idea get support from Jesus meting out a lesser punishment for the ignorant slave?

Comment: Is this strictly looking for an answer with a biblical basis? Different denominations might have different views on this.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to receive biblical references, thanks

Answer (score 4):

**is there a reason to believe that An existence in hell will be appreciably different in quality for each individual?**

> Revelation 20:12  And I saw the dead, small and great, stand before
>   God; and the books were opened: and another book was opened, which is
>   the book of life: and the dead were judged out of those things which
>   were written in the books, according to their works.

Each is judged according to their works.

There is also a parable about proportionality;

> Luke 12:47-48  And that servant, which knew his lord's will, and
>   prepared not himself, neither did according to his will, shall be
>   beaten with many stripes.  But he that knew not, and did commit things
>   worthy of stripes, shall be beaten with few stripes. For unto
>   whomsoever much is given, of him shall be much required: and to whom
>   men have committed much, of him they will ask the more.

God is just and his punishment is just.

God is also merciful.

> John 5:24  Verily, verily, I say unto you, He that heareth my word,
>   and believeth on him that sent me, hath everlasting life, and shall
>   not come into condemnation; but is passed from death unto life.